# What's the opposite of 'soporific'?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

I'm looking for an adjective to describe an effect which is the opposite of soporific:

> The insomniac's bedroom had a **[???]** effect: every time she went to bed, her tiredness disappeared and all she wanted was to get back up again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would asoporific work?

Comment: @Pureferret Does that mean "opposite of soporific" though, or just "not soporific"?

Comment: had a caffeinating effect...

Comment: @Drew: In context, perhaps *had a **stimulant** effect* is more likely. Maybe not more *likely* to the world at large, but it sounds more *appropriate* to me.

Comment: "... by the end of the fourteenth century English writers already possessed a range of techniques which could introduce variety and **counter soporific** tendencies,  ..." https://books.google.co.in/books?id=9USZCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=counter-soporific&source=bl&ots=GMtW5ooTnw&sig=VGIsDPdVCAnn0xZrNLFv28P7W8k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrg_n6g4zYAhUO448KHZPzDVoQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=counter-soporific&f=false

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not exactly the same, since it has meanings other than just non-drowsy, but you can probably use:

> ***invigorating***: *adj.* making one feel strong, healthy, and full of energy.

When talking about a soporific in terms of the noun, a drug that makes you drowsy, the opposite of that would be a *stimulant*, so you may also be able to use ***stimulating*** as an antonym. To me, though, that often has too much of an over-active ot hyper-active connotation to it.

Comment: This looks perfect. I'll accept it unless anyone comes up with something better.

Answer (score 4):

**awakening**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/awakening)

> adjective--1. rousing*; quickening
>
> *(*rousing* meaning to bring out of a state of sleep, unconsciousness, inactivity)

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/awakening)

> adjective--Rousing from sleep, in a natural or a figurative sense; rousing into activity; exciting; as, the awakening city; an awakening discourse; the awakening dawn.

---

**revitalizing**

[Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/revitalizing)

> adjective--having the ability or tendency to restore strength

**rejuvenating**

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/rejuvenating)

> adjective--having a renewing effect on the state of the body or mind

**stimulative**

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/stimulative)

> adjective--having a renewing effect on the state of the body or mind

**energizing**

[Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/energizing)

> adjective--that energizes someone

Comment: i would actually say rousing is a better choice then awakening (I wouldn't have expected that to even be an adjective)

Comment: @KutuluMike ~ the only problem with *rousing* is that it can also mean *exciting* and is usually used to describe experiences and other abstract ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite awhile ago, I see; but my advice is that your use of the "bedroom's effect" should be described as lacking the soporific  effect that it is supposed to have.